# vertical accordion from horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
//# jQuery - Horizontal Accordion
//# Version 2.00.00 Alpha 1
//#
//# portalZINE(R) - New Media Network
//# http://www.portalzine.de
//#
//# Alexander Graef
//# portalzine@gmail.com
//#
//# Copyright 2007-2009

(function($) {
    $.hrzAccordion = {


       setOnEvent: function(i, container, finalWidth, settings){
            $("#"+container+"Handle"+i).bind(settings.eventTrigger,function() {          

                        var status = $('[rel='+container+'ContainerSelected]').data('status');

                        if(status ==1 && settings.eventWaitForAnim === true){
                         return false;  
                        }

                        if( $("#"+container+"Handle"+i).attr("rel") != container+"HandleSelected"){

                          settings.eventAction;

                            $('[id*='+container+'Handle]').attr("rel","");                          

                            $('[id*='+container+'Handle]').attr("class",settings.handleClass);

                            $("#"+container+"Handle"+i).addClass(settings.handleClassSelected);


                            $("."+settings.contentWrapper).css({width: finalWidth+"px" });

                            switch(settings.closeOpenAnimation)
                            {
                            case 1:


                        if($('[rel='+container+'ContainerSelected]').get(0)  ){
                        $('[rel='+container+'ContainerSelected]').data('status',1);

                            //current_width = $('[rel='+container+'ContainerSelected]').width();

                            $('[rel='+container+'ContainerSelected]').animate({width: "0px",opacity:"0"}, { queue:true, duration:settings.closeSpeed ,easing:settings.closeEaseAction,complete: function(){ 

                            $('[rel='+container+'ContainerSelected]').data('status',0);                                                                                                                                                                         } ,step: function(now){
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    width = $(this).width();

                            //new_width = finalWidth- (finalWidth  * (width/current_width));
                            new_width = finalWidth - width;
                            $('#'+container+'Content'+i).width(Math.ceil(new_width)).css("opacity","1");

                            }});

                        }else{
                            $('[rel='+container+'ContainerSelected]').data('status',1);

                            $('#'+container+'Content'+i).animate({width: finalWidth,opacity:"1"}, { queue:false, duration:settings.closeSpeed ,easing:settings.closeEaseAction,complete: function(){
                                                                                                                                                                                                      $('[rel='+container+'ContainerSelected]').data('status',0);   
                                                                                                                                                                                                      }});


                            }

                            break;
                            case 2:
                                $('[id*='+container+'Content]').css({width: "0px"});
                                $('#'+container+'Content'+i).animate({width: finalWidth+"px",opacity:"1"}, { queue:false, duration:settings.openSpeed ,easing:settings.openEaseAction, complete: 
 settings.completeAction                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    });                     

                            break;
                            }

                            $('[id*='+container+'Content]').attr("rel","");         
                            $("#"+container+"Handle"+i).attr("rel",container+"HandleSelected");
                            $("#"+container+"Content"+i).attr("rel",container+"ContainerSelected");                 


                        }

                    }); 
}
        };

    $.fn.extend({

        hrzAccordionLoop: function(options) {
            return this.each(function(a){  

                var container = $(this).attr("id") || $(this).attr("class");
                var elementCount = $('#'+container+' > li, .'+container+' > li').size();
                var settings = $(this).data('settings');

                variable_holder="interval"+container ;
                var i =0;
                var loopStatus  = "start";

                variable_holder = window.setInterval(function(){                            

                $("#"+container+"Handle"+i).trigger(settings.eventTrigger);

                if(loopStatus =="start"){
                        i = i + 1;
                    }else{
                        i = i-1;    
                    }

                    if(i==elementCount && loopStatus  == "start"){
                        loopStatus  = "end";
                        i=elementCount-1;

                    }

                    if(i==0 && loopStatus  == "end"){
                        loopStatus  = "start";
                        i=0;

                    }
                                                },settings.cycleInterval);


                });
            },
        hrzAccordion: function(options) {
            this.settings = {
            eventTrigger            : "click",
            containerClass          : "container",
            listItemClass           : "listItem",                   
            contentContainerClass   : "contentContainer",
            contentWrapper          : "contentWrapper",
            contentInnerWrapper     : "contentInnerWrapper",
            handleClass             : "handle",
            handleClassOver         : "handleOver",
            handleClassSelected     : "handleSelected",
            handlePosition          : "right",
            handlePositionArray     : "", // left,left,right,right,right
            closeEaseAction         : "swing",
            closeSpeed              : 500,
            openEaseAction          : "swing",
            openSpeed               : 500,
            openOnLoad              : 2,
            hashPrefix              : "tab",
            eventAction             : function(){
                                    //add your own extra clickAction function here
                                    },
            completeAction          : function(){
                                    //add your own onComplete function here
                                    },
            closeOpenAnimation      : 1,// 1 - open and close at the same time / 2- close all and than open next
            cycle                   : false, // not integrated yet, will allow to cycle through tabs by interval
            cycleInterval           : 10000,
            fixedWidth              : "",
            eventWaitForAnim        : true

        };

        if(options){
            $.extend(this.settings, options);
        }
            var settings = this.settings;



            return this.each(function(a){           

                var container = $(this).attr("id") || $(this).attr("class");            

                $(this).data('settings', settings);

                $(this).wrap("<div class='"+settings.containerClass+"'></div>");

                var elementCount = $('#'+container+' > li, .'+container+' > li').size();

                var containerWidth =  $("."+settings.containerClass).width();

                var handleWidth = $("."+settings.handleClass).css("width");

                handleWidth =  handleWidth.replace(/px/,"");
                var finalWidth;
                var handle;

                if(settings.fixedWidth){
                    finalWidth = settings.fixedWidth;
                }else{
                    finalWidth = containerWidth-(elementCount*handleWidth)-handleWidth;
                }

                $('#'+container+' > li, .'+container+' > li').each(function(i) {

                    $(this).attr('id', container+"ListItem"+i);
                    $(this).attr('class',settings.listItemClass);
                    $(this).html("<div class='"+settings.contentContainerClass+"' id='"+container+"Content"+i+"'>"
                                 +"<div class=\""+settings.contentWrapper+"\">"
                                 +"<div class=\""+settings.contentInnerWrapper+"\">"
                                 +$(this).html()
                                 +"</div></div></div>");

                    if($("div",this).hasClass(settings.handleClass)){

                    var html = $("div."+settings.handleClass,this).attr("id",""+container+"Handle"+i+"").html();
                    $("div."+settings.handleClass,this).remove();

                     handle = "<div class=\""+settings.handleClass+"\" id='"+container+"Handle"+i+"'>"+html+"</div>";
                    }else{
                     handle = "<div class=\""+settings.handleClass+"\" id='"+container+"Handle"+i+"'></div>";
                    }



                    if(settings.handlePositionArray){
                        splitthis               = settings.handlePositionArray.split(",");
                        settings.handlePosition = splitthis[i];
                    }

                    switch(settings.handlePosition ){
                        case "left":
                        $(this).prepend( handle );
                        break;
                        case "right":   
                        $(this).append( handle );   
                        break;
                        case "top": 
                        $("."+container+"Top").append( handle );    
                        break;
                        case "bottom":  
                        $("."+container+"Bottom").append( handle ); 
                        break;
                    }                   

                    $("#"+container+"Handle"+i).bind("mouseover", function(){
                        $("#"+container+"Handle"+i).addClass(settings.handleClassOver);
                    });

                    $("#"+container+"Handle"+i).bind("mouseout", function(){
                        if( $("#"+container+"Handle"+i).attr("rel") != "selected"){
                            $("#"+container+"Handle"+i).removeClass(settings.handleClassOver);
                        }
                    });


                    $.hrzAccordion.setOnEvent(i, container, finalWidth, settings);              

                    if(i == elementCount-1){
                        $('#'+container+",."+container).show();                 
                    }



                    if(settings.openOnLoad !== false && i == elementCount-1){
                            var location_hash = location.hash;
                            location_hash  = location_hash.replace("#", "");    
                            if(location_hash.search(settings.hashPrefix) != '-1' ){
                            var tab = 1;
                            location_hash  = location_hash.replace(settings.hashPrefix, "");
                            }

                            if(location_hash && tab ==1){
                                $("#"+container+"Handle"+(location_hash)).attr("rel",container+"HandleSelected");
                                $("#"+container+"Content"+(location_hash)).attr("rel",container+"ContainerSelected");       
                                $("#"+container+"Handle"+(location_hash-1)).trigger(settings.eventTrigger);

                            }else{
                                $("#"+container+"Handle"+(settings.openOnLoad)).attr("rel",container+"HandleSelected");
                                $("#"+container+"Content"+(settings.openOnLoad)).attr("rel",container+"ContainerSelected"); 
                                $("#"+container+"Handle"+(settings.openOnLoad-1)).trigger(settings.eventTrigger);
                            }                   
                    }   
                }); 

                if(settings.cycle === true){
                    $(this).hrzAccordionLoop();
                }
            });             
        }       
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**Given is the code used for the accordion...please check out this [Accordion Link](http://www.portalzine.de/Horizontal_Accordion_Plugin_2/index.html). in the link there are four examples of accordions. I want the last accordion, i.e example 4, to be vertical.

Comment: i know the code is lengthy ...but i had no other options :(

Comment: helping someone and doing others job are two different things @Sify Juhy.

Comment: OP, would you fix the link - it is broken, and I don't have enough rep to fix it without making other changes.

Comment: i understand..but i am not very good at JS.

Comment: @Sify - what people are trying to tell you is that if you want help here, you need to zero in on the code that's causing you a problem, show that, and ask a specific question about why it's wrong.  Nobody is going to read 5 pages of code and engineer you a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

http://www.portalzine.de/Horizontal_Accordion_Plugin_2/lib/jquery.hrzAccordion.examples.js

Edit: the JS you've posted is, I think, the whole plugin. Just include the plugin on your page, plus jQuery, plus the relevant snippet from my link above.

Comment: i have this file..but i want the accordion to be vertical.

Comment: i already did that..its a horizontal accordion ...i want to change it to vertical accordion.

Comment: Ah, I see. That is a much more significant change, apologies. In that case you'll need to see what part of the plugin code is doing the horizontal animations, and modify them. I'd start off with the `new_width` stuff - this looks like it is setting some div widths, and you want to set some heights instead. Switching those around might work - give it a go?

Comment: Btw, you may find it easier to google for "vertical accordion jquery", as this is quite likely to find something :)